# There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

i encounter this problem when navigate from widget to another, i searched about it, and i saw that i should add (heroTag) with (FloatActionButton) but i don't have this widget ,
this is the problem message:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must
have a unique non-null tag.
In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <default FloatingActionButton tag>
├# Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Hero._allHeroesFor.inviteHero.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:268:11)
#1      Hero._allHeroesFor.inviteHero (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:279:8)
#2      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:298:21)
#3      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#4      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#5      ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#6      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#7      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5973:16)
#8      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#9      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5973:16)
#10     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#11     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#12     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#13     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#14     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#15     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#16     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#17     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5973:16)
#18     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#20     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#21     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#22     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#24     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#26     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#27     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#28     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#29     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#30     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#31     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#32     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#33     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#34     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#35     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#36     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#37     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#38     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#39     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#40     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#41     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#42     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#43     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#44     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#45     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#46     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#47     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#48     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#49     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#50     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#51     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#52     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#53     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#54     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#55     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#56     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#57     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#58     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#59     List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:302:8)
#60     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1312:36)
#61     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#62     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#63     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#64     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5973:16)
#65     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#66     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#67     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#68     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#69     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#70     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#71     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#72     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#73     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#74     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#75     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#76     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#77     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#78     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#79     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#80     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#81     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#82     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#83     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#84     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#85     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#86     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#87     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#88     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#89     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#90     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#91     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#92     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#93     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#94     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#95     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#96     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#97     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#98     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#99     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#100    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#101    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#102    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#103    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#104    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#105    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#106    _LayoutBuilderElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:70:14)
#107    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#108    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#109    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#110    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#111    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#112    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#113    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#114    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5973:16)
#115    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#116    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#117    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#118    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#119    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#120    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#121    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#122    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#123    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#124    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#125    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#126    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#127    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#128    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#129    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#130    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#131    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#132    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#133    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#134    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#135    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#136    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#137    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#138    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5973:16)
#139    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#140    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#141    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#142    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#143    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#144    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#145    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#146    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5973:16)
#147    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#148    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#149    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#150    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#151    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#152    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#153    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#154    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#155    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#156    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#157    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#158    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#159    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#160    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#161    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#162    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#163    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#164    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#165    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#166    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#167    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#168    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#169    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#170    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#171    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#172    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#173    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#174    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#175    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#176    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#177    Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
#178    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5861:14)
#179    Element.visitChildElements (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3174:5)
#180    Hero._allHeroesFor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:314:13)
#181    HeroController._startHeroTransition (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:840:53)
#182    HeroController._maybeStartHeroTransition.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:815:11)
#183    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1117:15)
#184    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1064:9)
#185    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:972:5)
#189    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:253:10)
#190    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:211:3)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: An exception was throw by _MapStream<User, MUser> listened by

════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.

Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must have a unique non-null tag.
In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <default FloatingActionButton tag>
```

this is my code, even if i delete the route, the problem still exist
main.dart:

```
child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => Map(),
          '/profile': (context) => Profile(), //todo-Osama: gives error!
          '/addMakan': (context) => AddMakan(),
        },
```

map.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MapState mapState = Provider.of<MapState>(context);
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            //Loading(),
            GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition: initialCamera,
              mapType: mapType,
              markers: mapState.markers,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
                mapCompleter.complete(controller);
                mapController = await mapCompleter.future;
              },
              onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) {
                mapCurrentCenter = position.target;
                if (!userControlMapType) {
                  if ((mapType == MapType.normal && position.zoom >= 18.0) ||
                      (mapType == MapType.satellite && position.zoom < 18.0))
                    mapState.changeMapType();
                }
              },
            ),
            Tiles(),
            //TilesNew(), //todo-Osama: error here!
            Buttons(),
            Search(),
          ],
```

search.dart : i call it inside map.dart

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: 36,
      left: 10.0,
      right: 10.0,
      child: Container(
        height: 50.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        ),
        child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0), //todo: ?
          child: Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 34, color: Colors.blue[700]),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/profile'),
              ),
              Text('|', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black26, fontSize: 36.0)),
```

profile.dart : profile alone is working, but the problem when i navigate to it

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = 'profile';
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  Auth _auth = Auth();
  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
  bool titleHasError;
  bool bodyHasError;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MUser user = Provider.of<MUser>(context);
    return Hero(
      tag: Text("hero"),
      child: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            elevation: 8.0,
            title: Text('دخول / تسجيل / اسم عضو'),
          ),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32.0, horizontal: 16.0),
            child: FormBuilder(
              key: _fbKey,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height: 32.0),
```

Comment: the type for your hero tag is not a widget but a string. and also make sure the tag is unique for example maybe the userId... it would have been better if you can share the Widget where the hero is coming from....

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell where the problem is without seeing all Hero tag references BUT, I suggest changing all your Hero tags to String (not Text('...') ) and making sure they are unique.

For example, in a ListView, Hero tags could be `'$itemName+${itemIndex}'`

Update:

```
Hero(
  tag: "avatar-$index",
  child: Image.network(
           "https://picsum.photos/seed/$index/800",
           fit: BoxFit.cover,
         ),
  ),
```

You must use the same tag on both ends of the Hero pair.

Update:
This is required every time you use a Hero widget (Hero widget provides for the Hero animation). If you are not try to acheive a Hero animation, then do not use the Hero widget.

Remove the Hero widget from your profile.dart.

Comment: but why this problem? it is the first time i encounter like this?

Comment: how can i add hero tag? i tried to use heroTag but it is not exist in most of widget

Comment: i dont't understand !! why hero? i create many apps before, and i have never used hero or tag at all? what is the different now? i tried this also doesn't work

Comment: yes, actually, i had many floatActionButtons in my app, so just add heroTag  to it, and should be unique

Comment: Great. If you feel my answer helped, please mark it as the accepted answer.